# Apple Mail adds blank rows to CSV file

Tags: mail.app, catalina, ms-office, csv

I'm having an odd problem. I've recently decided to try Apple Mail as my default mail platform. Everything is being great until a coworker noticed that the **.csv** files I send come out with *blank rows* in between.

- This is the original file (randomly generated for this example).
  [image]
- This is the file sent by another mail platform (Outlook Desktop for example),
  and opened with TextEdit app or Notepad in windows.
  [image]
- This is the file sent with Apple mail on Mac, and opened with TextEdit app or Notepad in windows.
  [image]

I've been looking into resources, and apparently there is some different with formats using such as CR in Mac, and CRLF in windows but I still can't answer this questions.

1. Why does this happen?
2. Is there a setting I can correct in Excel?
3. Is there a setting I can correct in the Mail app?
4. Will this happen with other types of files?

Any help on this is appreciated!

**Note: File also has blank rows when opening in Excel, or Numbers **after** it was sent through Apple Mail. Before this, the file looks normal in all apps mentioned above.**

Comment: Is your csv in UTF-8 or other when exporting from Excel?

Comment: Yes! I exported as CSV UTF-8, and as regular CSV. They both come out the same, but as soon as they are sent by Apple mail all of the sudden they have they blank rows.

Comment: Will you also entertain solutions to the problem even without reasons for the problem?

Comment: Hi Jeffrey, can you elaborate on your question?

Answer (score 1):

There's a long thread on it [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/252594272?login=true), and it seems to be an issue caused by the Mac Mail client that's been reported for around 10 years now, but with no fix. I've found that if you send the file from the in-browser email client then the attachment will be fine on the other end.